# How to enable Streamset Mutitenancy using LDAP Authentication

Tags: authentication, ldap, roles, streamsets

I am using Streamset Data Collector version 3.19.1, currently am trying to integrate Streamset with LDAP server for authentication, I am successful with the integration however we are facing difficulties in configuring the roles and groups like the way it is in File based.
i.e in file based you have three things to configure a)user b)role c) group

```
<user name>: MD5:<md5-text>, user, <role> [, <additional role>, <additional role>...] [, group:<group>, group:<additional group>...]
```

if you look at above syntax, there is **user name** which can be user defined, then there is **user** which is fixed value, then we have **role** it can be one of (Admin,Manager,Creator and guest) and last we have group which us again user defined this can be used for Multitenancy.

however now comparing to LDAP configuration provided by streamset we have only following attributes to configure.

```
<ldap group>:<SDC role>,<additional SDC role>,<additional SDC role>);<ldap group>:<SDC role>,<additional SDC role>...
```

from above syntax we can see  can be configured which is user defined and SDC role which can be one of the following(Admin,Manager,Creator and guest) with this the configuration will look like

```
DEV:creator;OPS:manager;
```

how can I configure LDAP rule mapping for **group** and **role**, currently i can only map for role in LDAP, requesting anyone to help here, i tried all my best to resolve unfortunately couldnt find any solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same configuration for groups as well. Following from my environment.

```
http.authentication.ldap.role.mapping=operators:admin;
```

To get the groups ldap-login-conf needs to be configured like following:-

```
roleBaseDn="OU=operations,OU=test_groups,OU=groups,OU=sdc,DC=example,DC=COM"
roleNameAttribute="cn"
roleMemberAttribute="member"
roleObjectClass="group"
roleFilter="member={dn}";
```